# Free Editable Table

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a free editable react table control to insert into my React Application.
The table will need to have various type of columns (text column, date column, ect) and all of them have to be editable.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would this work? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editable-table

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable is the best solution for the free table. See the website https://datatables.net/

Comment: It requires jQuery though